# Advantages and differences between passing string literals or const char[] to functions

Tags: c, string, arguments, literals

let's say i have a program where i print the same line to the console multiple times throughout it's execution and the line needs to be passed to printf() multiple times.

on the surface the option at the bottom all do of course the same thing in so far that the end result is the same but i am not sure about the actual differences between them in terms of memory-performance, compiler optimization (considering that #define is a preprocessor keyword), safety and convention.

since i mainly work on micro controllers a possible performance advantage from one over the other would actually make a difference but regardles of that i am curious what the technical differences between those three are and wich one is preferable

1.

```
#include "stdio.h"

const char string_to_print[] = "Hello Stackoverflow\n";

int main()
{
    printf(string_to_print);
    printf(string_to_print);
    printf(string_to_print);
    printf(string_to_print);

    return 0;
}
```

2. 

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello Stackoverflow\n");
    printf("Hello Stackoverflow\n");
    printf("Hello Stackoverflow\n");
    printf("Hello Stackoverflow\n");

    return 0;
}
```

3. 

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define STRING_TO_PRINT "Hello Stackoverflow\n"

int main()
{
    printf(STRING_TO_PRINT);
    printf(STRING_TO_PRINT);
    printf(STRING_TO_PRINT);
    printf(STRING_TO_PRINT);

    return 0;
}
```

sorry if this has been asked before, i searched for 10 minutes and didn't find anything useful but maybe i am just bad at searching

Comment: The last two options are semantically the same.  The first one is semantically very similar, but might be handled slightly differently by the compiler.  Any way around, and don't see any strong reasons to favor one of these over the others.

Comment: In general it's a good idea to give a name to something you use repeatedly. So if you want to change it, you just have to change it in one place. Whether you use a macro or a variable doesn't matter much.

Comment: Questions about general programming guidelines like this are more appropriate for [softwareengineering.se].

Comment: I would prefer the first option, since it explicitly stores the string once. The other two rely on the compiler optimising things for you. I'd use `puts()` or similar though, in case your string has some `%` in it.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Any compiler that doesn't optimize the other cases is not worth thinking about. And even if it doesn't, memory is cheap unless you're programming a microcontroller.

Comment: The char array allocate the memory for whole program. If you have multiple functions and classes then preferable way is to use DEFINE. If you just have a single main, then instead of persisting memory for a whole function, you should manually write it. These differences can be important for low memory MCU, but for computers doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @Barmar wich i am (as stated in the question) wich is why i am asking

Comment: @umairmughal this puts in a bit of a conundrum because i don't have any classes but i do have multiple functions

Comment: @xXRunDeathXx OK. My first point still stands. Literal pools have been a well known technology for decades. There's no excuse for a compiler not implementing this trivial optimization.

Comment: @Barmar very true, yes. also i didn't know about the existence of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ . i will post this kind of question there next time. thank you

Comment: Why not 4. `const char *string_to_print = "Hello Stackoverflow\n";`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer

1. The first code. Many optimizing compilers will keep 2 copies of the string. One with `'\n'` and one without as it will try to optimize out the `printf` function and it needs to keep the array as it was used. https://godbolt.org/z/nEahszd3x. If you change `const char string_to_print[] = "Hello Stackoverflow";` it will keep only one copy
2. The second code - it will keep only one copy.
3. third and the 4 code are identical as macros are textually replaced before the C comilation and the C compiler will compile exactly the same code.

But as a general rule - do not try to micro-optimize your code unless you **have to**. Focus on the main task and if you have performance or resources problems start to micro-optimize.

Comment: Your point 1) is interesting and very weird. Never seen that before! I guess in your point 3) you meant 2nd and 3rd.